# Use HAproxy (SSL) in front of http proxy

Tags: proxy, https, haproxy

I'm currently trying to build myself an app which is able to load-balance traffic between my [polipo](https://www.irif.fr/~jch/software/polipo/) processes. With http everything is working find but as soon as I turn over to https haproxy simply shows "400 bad" request any idea why?

This is my setup :

```
                                                <-> Polipo 1 (http) 
Client <----> (https) HAproxy <----> (http)     <-> Polipo 2 (http)
                                                <-> Polipo 3 (http)
```

This is my HAproxy config:

```
global
  maxconn 4096 
  daemon
  tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
  ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
  ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3
  pidfile <%= pid_file %>

defaults
  mode http
  maxconn 4096
  option  httplog
  option  dontlognull
  option forwardfor
  option http-server-close
  retries 3
  timeout connect 5s
  timeout client 60s
  timeout server 60s




frontend rotating_proxies
  bind *:<%= port %> ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/mydomain.pem
  reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
  default_backend polipo
  option http_proxy


backend polipo
  option http_proxy
  http-response replace-value Location ^http://(.*)$ https://\1
  redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
  balance leastconn



  <% backends.each do |b| %>
  server <%= b[:name] %><%= b[:port] %> <%= b[:addr] %>:<%= b[:port] %> check maxconn 4096
  <% end %>
```

I'm not sure about

```
http-response replace-value Location ^http://(.*)$ https://\1
```

What exactly does that mean? Polipo is only talking http (unencrypted).
HAproxy should simply do ssl offloading.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: It's ok, it's the public URL, and remove `option http_proxy`.

Quoting [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location):

> The Location response header indicates the URL to redirect a page to. It only provides a meaning when served with a 3xx (redirection) or 201 (created) status response.

The redirection has to be performed by the user-agent and thus has to be presented the correct URL to be used when accessing HAProxy.

From the [HAProxy docs](https://www.haproxy.org/download/1.8/doc/configuration.txt):

> option http_proxy
>   [...]
>   In this mode, no server is declared, and the connection is forwarded to
>     the IP address and port found in the URL after the "http://" scheme.

This is not what you want. Drop the directive.

Comment: Can you please add the config as you thing it should be?! Would be awsome, thx.